# Elastic Beanstalk Redis Fail, Webapp Unresponsive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, sidekiq

Can't get past sidekiq errors.

Trying to migrate from Heroku to AWS EB. I have a rails app running rails 4.2.0, ruby 2.3 on a linux machine, but keep running into issues. The webapp won't load - it simply times out over and over.

```
INFO: Running in ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]
INFO: See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
INFO: Upgrade to Sidekiq Pro for more features and support: http://sidekiq.org
INFO: Booting Sidekiq 3.5.4 with redis options {:url=>nil}
ERROR: heartbeat: MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but is currently not able to persist on disk. Commands that may modify the data set are disabled. Please check Redis logs for details about the error.
```

Redis keeps telling me its `url is nil` despite what seems to be a solid setup. (It works on another app I managed to get running with the same configuration. I also found the ERROR MISCONF notice to be troublesome too, but the Redis URL isn't even setting. Further, both are in the same security group

This is my **config/sidekiq.rb**:

```
rails_root = Rails.root || File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../..'
rails_env = Rails.env || 'development'
redis_config = YAML.load_file(rails_root.to_s + '/config/redis.yml')
redis_config.merge! redis_config.fetch(Rails.env, {})
redis_config.symbolize_keys!

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: "redis://#{ENV['REDIS_HOST']}:#{redis_config[:port]}/12" }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: "redis://#{ENV['REDIS_HOST']}:#{redis_config[:port]}/12" }
end
```

And my **config/redis.yml**:

```
development:
  host: localhost
  port: 6379
test:
  host: localhost
  port: 6379
production:
  host: ENV['REDIS_HOST']
  port: 6379
```

My **applicatoin.yml**:

```
REDIS_HOST: project-name-001.random-token.0001.use1.cache.amazonaws.com
```

[Here's](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2cb1e0961657502e1cdded814ce5a77a) the `setup_swap.config`, `sidekiq.config`, and `nginx.config`.

I've also seen this issue, but I assume it's unrelated. Perhaps I'm mistaken? If irrelevant, will address in another post.

```
Starting nginx: nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
```

What could it be?
Is there anything important I'm missing?

**Edit: Add nginx.conf**

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    index   index.html index.htm;

    server {
        listen       80 ;
        listen       [::]:80 ;
        server_name  localhost;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /40x.html
        #
        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2 ;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 ;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
#        ssl_ciphers <redacted>;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        location / {
#        }
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }

}
```

**Updated response:** I updated `nginx.conf` to read: `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/webapp_healthd.conf;` but still got the following:

```
[root] service nginx restart
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
Stopping nginx:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting nginx: nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
                                                       [  OK  ]
```

And also, the following persists:

```
ERROR: heartbeat: MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, 
but is currently not able to persist on disk. Commands that may modify 
the data set are disabled. Please check Redis logs for details about 
the error.
```

**Update 2** removed duplicate references to localhost port 80 and nginx stopped complaining, but I still get the `Heartbeat MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but is currently not able to persist on disk.` error.

Output from `Sidekiq.redis(&:info)`:

```
{ 
  "redis_version"=>"3.2.8", 
  "redis_git_sha1"=>"00000000", 
  "redis_git_dirty"=>"0", 
  "redis_build_id"=>"12e5c8be08dc4d3", 
  "redis_mode"=>"standalone", 
  "os"=>"Linux 4.4.51-40.60.amzn1.x86_64 x86_64", 
  "arch_bits"=>"64", 
  "multiplexing_api"=>"epoll", 
  "gcc_version"=>"4.8.3", 
  "process_id"=>"24835", 
  "run_id"=>"83a8de8b50f482a4e271228435b2f0c8e3fa5b5c", 
  "tcp_port"=>"6379", 
  "uptime_in_seconds"=>"341217", 
  "uptime_in_days"=>"3", 
  "hz"=>"10", 
  "lru_clock"=>"1108155", 
  "executable"=>"/usr/local/bin/redis-server", 
  "config_file"=>"/etc/redis/redis.conf", 
  "connected_clients"=>"2", 
  "client_longest_output_list"=>"0", 
  "client_biggest_input_buf"=>"0", 
  "blocked_clients"=>"0", 
  "used_memory"=>"842664", 
  "used_memory_human"=>"822.91K", 
  "used_memory_rss"=>"3801088", 
  "used_memory_rss_human"=>"3.62M", 
  "used_memory_peak"=>"924360", 
  "used_memory_peak_human"=>"902.70K", 
  "total_system_memory"=>"1043574784", 
  "total_system_memory_human"=>"995.23M", 
  "used_memory_lua"=>"37888", 
  "used_memory_lua_human"=>"37.00K", 
  "maxmemory"=>"0", 
  "maxmemory_human"=>"0B", 
  "maxmemory_policy"=>"noeviction", 
  "mem_fragmentation_ratio"=>"4.51", 
  "mem_allocator"=>"jemalloc-4.0.3", 
  "loading"=>"0", 
  "rdb_changes_since_last_save"=>"177", 
  "rdb_bgsave_in_progress"=>"0", 
  "rdb_last_save_time"=>"1493941570", 
  "rdb_last_bgsave_status"=>"err", 
  "rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec"=>"0", 
  "rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec"=>"-1", 
  "aof_enabled"=>"0", 
  "aof_rewrite_in_progress"=>"0", 
  "aof_rewrite_scheduled"=>"0", 
  "aof_last_rewrite_time_sec"=>"-1", 
  "aof_current_rewrite_time_sec"=>"-1", 
  "aof_last_bgrewrite_status"=>"ok", 
  "aof_last_write_status"=>"ok", 
  "total_connections_received"=>"17", 
  "total_commands_processed"=>"141824", 
  "instantaneous_ops_per_sec"=>"0", 
  "total_net_input_bytes"=>"39981126", 
  "total_net_output_bytes"=>"72119284", 
  "instantaneous_input_kbps"=>"0.00", 
  "instantaneous_output_kbps"=>"0.00", 
  "rejected_connections"=>"0", 
  "sync_full"=>"0", 
  "sync_partial_ok"=>"0", 
  "sync_partial_err"=>"0", 
  "expired_keys"=>"3", 
  "evicted_keys"=>"0", 
  "keyspace_hits"=>"14", 
  "keyspace_misses"=>"533", 
  "pubsub_channels"=>"0", 
  "pubsub_patterns"=>"0", 
  "latest_fork_usec"=>"160", 
  "migrate_cached_sockets"=>"0", 
  "role"=>"master", 
  "connected_slaves"=>"0", 
  "master_repl_offset"=>"0", 
  "repl_backlog_active"=>"0", 
  "repl_backlog_size"=>"1048576", 
  "repl_backlog_first_byte_offset"=>"0", 
  "repl_backlog_histlen"=>"0", 
  "used_cpu_sys"=>"167.52", 
  "used_cpu_user"=>"46.03", 
  "used_cpu_sys_children"=>"0.00", 
  "used_cpu_user_children"=>"0.00", 
  "cluster_enabled"=>"0", 
  "db0"=>"keys=1,expires=0,avg_ttl=0"
}
```

Interestingly, I can't find my redis logs to investigate further. In my `redis.conf`, all I see is this.

```
# Specify the log file name. Also the empty string can be used to force
# Redis to log on the standard output. Note that if you use standard
# output for logging but daemonize, logs will be sent to /dev/null
logfile ""
```

I've even run `find / -path /sys -prune -o -path /proc -prune -o -name *redis*` and don't see ANY log files. (╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻

What's also strange is that **production.log** is simply not getting written to, check the permissions: rw-r--r-- 1 webapp webapp 0 May 8 20:01 production.log

Answer (score 3):

Please share your `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, I guess `nginx.conf` include other servers conf files in `conf.d` folder, check for the line `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` in your `nginx.conf`, if so it might load the file twice or other default file with the same `server name`, you can change it to `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/webapp_healthd.conf` or what ever name you want, but before check what is the file on the machine.

Also Check out the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` directory if there is any temp file such as `~default` or `.save`. check it with `ls -lah`, delete them, restart nginx and check for errors or do it via `ebextensions` and deploy again.

**UPDATE**

Try to remove from `nginx.conf`all the section of `server { ... }`, make sure to include inside `http` your file `/etc/nginx/conf.d/webapp_healthd.conf`, there you already have  `server listen 80;` and `localhost`..

nginx.conf

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/webapp_healthd.conf;

    index   index.html index.htm;
}
```

003_nginx.config

```
files:
    "/etc/nginx/conf.d/webapp_healthd.conf" :
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            upstream my_app {
              server unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock;
            }

            log_format healthd '$msec"$uri"'
                            '$status"$request_time"$upstream_response_time"'
                            '$http_x_forwarded_for';

            server {
              listen 80;
              server_name _ localhost; # need to listen to localhost for worker tier
              root /var/app/current/public;

              if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
                set $year $1;
                set $month $2;
                set $day $3;
                set $hour $4;
              }

              access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
              access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;

              try_files $uri/index.html $uri @my_app;

              location @my_app {
                proxy_pass http://my_app; # match the name of upstream directive which is defined above
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
              }

              location /assets {
                alias /var/app/current/public/assets;
                gzip_static on;
                gzip on;
                expires max;
                add_header Cache-Control public;
              }
                      # redirect server error pages to the static page /40x.html
              #
              error_page 404 /404.html;
                  location = /40x.html {
              }

              # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
              #
              error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
                 location = /50x.html {
              }
            }
    "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/03_restart_nginx.sh":
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            #!/usr/bin/env bash
            rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/webapp_healthd.conf.bak
            rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/custom.conf
            service nginx restart
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! I've added the `nginx.conf` file, and I did notice the `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` but when I went to check `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`, I found nothing. There is no such directory... what does this mean?

Comment: Also, changed to include `webapp_healthd.conf` (it's there on the machine). See updated description @Berlin

Comment: i think its because in `nginx conf` and `webapp_healthd.conf` you have server that listen to port 80

Comment: @Berlin- thanks so much - there was a dupe! Still getting `MISCONF Redis is currently not able to persist on disk.` error. 

Tried to investigate but the `redis logs` simply don't exist in /var/logs!? Any ideas? redis.conf is like reading latin.

What's also strange is that **production.log** is simply not getting written to, check the permissions:
`rw-r--r-- 1 webapp webapp     0 May  8 20:01 production.log`

Comment: did you installed local redis on this machine for this env ? if so let me know and we change the redis conf file, what is the redis version ? is the only line on your `redis.conf` is `logfilg` ? also what is happen now after you changed the `nginx.conf` , are you able to access your app via the browser ?

Comment: yes i think installation should be fine - see `ruby.config` in the [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2cb1e0961657502e1cdded814ce5a77a#file-ruby-config). It's `"redis_version"=>"3.2.8"`. Here is the full [redis.conf](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/44adafd554c0e27df9e5791059818c1a) Sadly, when I try to visit site, it still times out. Only useful error I have is the `heartbeat: MISCONF Redis not able to persist on disk.` from **sidekiq.log**. I assume it's related to not having a redis log file. @Berlin

Comment: @SomeoneElse how much memory the machine have (which instance type) ? and are you connecting from rails to redis without password right (from what i see) ?

Comment: It's on the t2.micro tier and I've implemented redis thru elasticache. they  both share the same default VPC. @Berlin

Comment: but if you implemented redis throw elastic cache , why do you need to install redis on your rails machine ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143809/discussion-between-someone-else-and-berlin).

Comment: any progress with the issue ?